# Arquillan EJB test not running

Tags: unit-testing, ejb, jboss-arquillian

I wrote an Arquillan test, but nothing seems to happen after deployment annotation

```
@RunWith(Arquillian.class) 
public class EjbTest {

@Inject
private RepAlertManager ejb;


@Deployment
public static Archive<?> createDeployment() {
    return ShrinkWrap.create(JavaArchive.class, "foo.jar")
    .addClasses(RepAlertManagerImpl.class)
    .addAsManifestResource(EmptyAsset.INSTANCE, "beans.xml");
}

@Test
public void testEjb() throws IOException, SQLException {

    try 
    {

        List<Long> result = ejb.doSomething("ENTRATE");

        for(Long temp:result){
            System.out.println(temp);
        }

    } 
    catch (Exception e) 
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
  }
}
```

I run it from Eclipse as JUnit Test, but debug goes out deployment method after nothing happens

Comment: Can you try it on the command line? what build tool do you use, maven?

Comment: I used gradle, but I must search for the file because I've backuped this project

Comment: Is it executing your test?